# How to load the data using Ajax in Django template?

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

Using Ajax in Django is a open Issue. I have tried to understand it by reading blogs and forums, but it didn't work for me. I am posting a very simple question related to it.

Method defined in views.py: (just a sample)

```
def widget_data(request):
    ####
    extra_context = {
        'data': username
        'part': company
        }
    return direct_to_template(request,'test/widgets.html',
                              extra_context)
```

I want to load `extra_context` to rendered template using `Ajax`.

Following things will happen in `widget.html` template i.e.

When a moderator will type a URL at the address bar to open a page it will load two widgets i.e. one for loading all the registered username and other one for their company name . user are continuously registering to the sites and adding company name to their profile. When a new user will registered to the site both widget should load automatically using Ajax.

I have no idea about the topic of Ajax. 
How to do this?
 How should i even start this?

I have read these following links :
[Tutorial 1](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jul/31/django-tips-simple-ajax-example-part-1/)
[Tutorial 2](http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/)

I know that the answer will be too long and too messy but any help will be appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery you can do the following

```
$.get('/url/of/widget_data/view', success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  $('#idofdivtoupdate').html(data);
});
```

That would probably be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I am no well i Jquery but somehow i tried to understand that ***data*** in success is the one which are relate to username. If it is then what about the other one i.e. ***part***. How should i load that ?